# Using Pharrell Willaim's 'Happy' song for Organizational Video

Tags: copyright

I would like to shoot a small video in our organization using Pharrell William's 'Happy' song. What about IP issues, if any! We are trying to promote our company brand through it. But there wont be any mention in the song, as such! The song stays unmodified. We would mostly go for a small logo at some part in the screen.

Please help me in DMR